# Scala Futures. Action if one of several fails

Tags: scala, exception, future

I have a situation where I want to execute several tasks concurrently as a future so that if one of them fails, the others will still execute.
If one fails I want to log it's error.
I want my parent thread to be able to tell if each one has succeeded or not and then perform some action based on that. Eg, if one of the futures failed, print "Hey, one of the futures failed"

```
val futureA = Future(doTaskThatReturnsABoolean)
val futureB = Future(doTaskThatReturnsABoolean)
val futureC = Future(doTaskThatReturnsABoolean)

futureA.onFailure (case t => println(future A failed ) + t.getMessage)
futureB.onFailure (case t => println(future B failed ) + t.getMessage)
futureC.onFailure (case t => println(future C failed ) + t.getMessage)

if (one of these futures failed) {
  println("One of the futures failed")
  throw new someNewError
}
```

If any or all of the futures fails, I want to get their stack trace logged but I don't want to then cause my whole program to error until all futures have had a chance to run. Because they could all error for different reasons, I don't want to just repeat their error, I want to throw a new one.

I've been reading http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html but just can't get my head round this one.

I don't want to use "Await" as that requires a time and I want to give the futures as much time as they want to run. Let's assume for now that they "will" complete but in an undetermined timeframe that depends entirely on data size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
val futureA = Future(doTaskThatReturnsABoolean).recoverWith{
  case e:Throwable => println(future A failed ) + t.getMessage; Future.failed(e)
}
val futureB = Future(doTaskThatReturnsABoolean).recoverWith{
  case e:Throwable => println(future B failed ) + t.getMessage; Future.failed(e)
}
val futureC = Future(doTaskThatReturnsABoolean).recoverWith{
  case e:Throwable => println(future  failed ) + t.getMessage; Future.failed(e)
}

val futures = List(futureA, futureB, futureC)
Future.sequence(futures).recoverWith{
  case p:Throwable => println("One of the futures failed"); Future.failed(new SomeNewError)
}
```

`Future.sequence` helper method converts collections of futures into a future wrapping the collection of results. If one of the source futures fails the resulting future will be failed.

Comment: Thanks! That worked a treat. I modified slightly to get what I wanted as I wanted the new error to be thrown.
`Future.sequence(futures).onFailure{`
`throw new SomeNewError`
`}`

Comment: Throwing in onFailure doesn't do what you think